# Apply p5.js file as a background

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js

I've made a starry heaven like background with some particles like this:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  particles.push(createVector(random(width), random(height)));
  stroke(82, 48, 192);
}
}

function draw() {
  background(0, 10)
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    let p = particles[i];
    point(p.x, p.y);
  }
}
```

I wan to apply it to a html page as a background. I've managed to append it with the `parent()` function but it displays under the div I've appended it to. Is there a way to really make this the background instead of placing it under it at the page?

Comment: you cannot use a JS file for the `background`-property as it is not an image. However, you can use it to manipulate a pseudo-element that is pushed to the background with a negative z-index.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that on YouTube as well. When I use the negative z-index it still remains at the bottom of the page with the normal page above it. So I've appended it correctly but it doesn't act as a background at start if you know what I mean:)

Comment: I made the default background transparant and used the z-index -1. Now it's working fine.

Comment: you can also move the default background to the pseudo-element if you want a specific default background.